# compare two columns in two dataframes in panda and if they are similar getting the values of another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames like this

```
df1
      Entry           Sequence
0    A0A024QZ18    MSGLEMADHMMAMNHGRFPDGTNGLHHHPAHRMGMGQFPSPHHHQQ
1    A0A024QZ42    MAALSGGGGGGAEPGQALFNGDMEPEAGAGAGAAASSAADPAIPf
2    A0A024QZB8    MLWWEEVEDCYEREDVQKKTFTKWVNAQFSKFGKQHIENLFSDLQD
3    A0A024QZP7    MARFGDEMPARYGGGGSGAAAGVVVGSGGGRGAGGSRQGGQPGAQR
4    A0A024QZX5    MRPDRAEAPGPPAMAAGGPGAGSAAPVSSTSSLPLAALNMRVRRRL
5    A0A024QZ33    MNSPGGRGKKKGSGGASNPVPPRPPPPCLAPAPPAAGPAPPPESPH

df2

    Seq_id       number
0   A0A024QZ18     67
1   A0A024QZ33     45
2   A0A024QZ42     252
3   A0A024QZB8     35
4   A0A024QZP7     34
5   A0A024QZX5     54
```

I want to check which Entry in dataFrame df1 is there in Se Seq_id in df2 and if there are present, I want to print the Sequence in df1 as a new column in df2 infrot of similar id. If they are not present print ‘nan’.

```
Example answer:

    Seq_id       number   Sequence
0   A0A024QZ18     67     MSGLEMADHMMAMNHGRFPDGTNGLHHHPAHRMGMGQFPSPHHHQQ
1   A0A024QZ33     45     MNSPGGRGKKKGSGGASNPVPPRPPP
2   A0A024QZ42     252    MAALSGGGGGGAEPGQALFNGDMEPEAG
3   A0A024QZB8     35     MLWWEEVEDCYEREDVQKKTFTKWVNAQFSKFGKQHIENLFSDLQD...
4   A0A024QZP7     34     MARFGDEMPARYGGGGSGAAAGVVVGSGG
5   A0A024QZX5     54     MRPDRAEAPGPPAMAAGGPGAGSAAPVSS
```

I was trying whether they are in the prsent in the column as follows

df2.seq_id.isin(df_seq.Entry)

But i don't know how to print another column if they are similar, and gives nan if they are not.

Comment: what happens when there is no match?

Comment: @luigigi Just want it to come as 'nan'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, simple left join will satisfy your requirements.

```
df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='Entry', right_on='Seq_id')
```

which will give you the output

```
     Entry                                        Sequence      Seq_id  number
 A0A024QZ18  MSGLEMADHMMAMNHGRFPDGTNGLHHHPAHRMGMGQFPSPHHHQQ  A0A024QZ18      67
 A0A024QZ42   MAALSGGGGGGAEPGQALFNGDMEPEAGAGAGAAASSAADPAIPf  A0A024QZ42     252
 A0A024QZB8  MLWWEEVEDCYEREDVQKKTFTKWVNAQFSKFGKQHIENLFSDLQD  A0A024QZB8      35
 A0A024QZP7  MARFGDEMPARYGGGGSGAAAGVVVGSGGGRGAGGSRQGGQPGAQR  A0A024QZP7      34
 A0A024QZX5  MRPDRAEAPGPPAMAAGGPGAGSAAPVSSTSSLPLAALNMRVRRRL  A0A024QZX5      54
 A0A024QZ33  MNSPGGRGKKKGSGGASNPVPPRPPPPCLAPAPPAAGPAPPPESPH  A0A024QZ33      45
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and this is great. Sorry my dataframes are big and I have given a little here,There will be non matching ones. I want to get 'nan' for those. Can you help in this

Comment: If there is a non matching row, it will be automatically filled as `NaN`.